# Can't access chef-manage web interface after a reboot - CentOS 6

Tags: chef-infra, centos6.5

I am very new to Chef. I had installed Chef in Centos6.6 and could 
access Chef control panel https://myservername.com

However, after reboot I cannot access Chef control panel via
https://myservername.com. It does not load anything!!!

I have followed this instruction
https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html

I have start the server

```
    [root@chefsv1 ~]# chef-server-ctl status
run: bookshelf: (pid 807) 374s; run: log: (pid 791) 374s
run: nginx: (pid 1572) 360s; run: log: (pid 795) 374s
run: oc_bifrost: (pid 811) 374s; run: log: (pid 794) 374s
run: oc_id: (pid 808) 374s; run: log: (pid 792) 374s
run: opscode-erchef: (pid 825) 374s; run: log: (pid 801) 374s
run: opscode-expander: (pid 805) 374s; run: log: (pid 790) 374s
run: opscode-expander-reindexer: (pid 806) 374s; run: log: (pid 789) 374s
run: opscode-pushy-server: (pid 846) 374s; run: log: (pid 824) 374s
run: opscode-reporting: (pid 847) 374s; run: log: (pid 826) 374s
run: opscode-solr4: (pid 809) 374s; run: log: (pid 793) 374s
run: postgresql: (pid 823) 374s; run: log: (pid 816) 374s
run: rabbitmq: (pid 802) 374s; run: log: (pid 787) 374s
run: redis_lb: (pid 804) 374s; run: log: (pid 788) 374s

[root@chefsv1 ~]# opscode-manage-ctl status
run: opscode-manage-events: (pid 784) 296s; run: log: (pid 781) 296s
run: opscode-manage-webapp: (pid 764) 296s; run: log: (pid 762) 297s
run: opscode-manage-worker: (pid 766) 296s; run: log: (pid 765) 296s
run: redis: (pid 782) 296s; run: log: (pid 763) 296s
```

Do I need to start any other service?

Comment: I assume you're using version 12 of chef-server, however you don't show the output of `opscode-manage-ctl status` which manages the services for the [chef-manage](http://docs.chef.io/manage.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, the version is 12. I have added the output.

Comment: Any logs ? Does `Chef-server-ctl tail` or opscode-manage-ctl tail` show your attempts ? Don't you have another apache or nginx system already using port 443 ? (and IIRC the web-ui is at https://server/chef-manage)

Comment: Thanks again. It is fixed now. Centos's default iptables was blocking it.

Comment: you may delete this question so, it won't be of use to anyone else later with this kind of description

Comment: I think it is better to keep it as it is very confusing for a newbie to troubleshoot as they know very little about chef. The real issue is with CentOS but one may think it is chef issue.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with programming altogether, it's Off-Topic to SO as it's a system administration problem. Even more it's maybe related to your install method of centos 6.6. If you really wish to keep it 1) migrate it to SuperUser, 2) rephrase it so it's clear the problem is "Can't access chef-manage web interface after a reboot". At end it's tightly coupled to the fact you're using chef-manage which is an add-on. People with real "chef-server not starting" problem because off berkshelf or postgres or even rabbitmq errors won't find anything useful here.

Comment: As a newbie, I thought it is part of Chef. I did not know it is a Add-on.Your title make sense and I have changed it. Thanks for that.

Comment: you installed it separately from the chef-server, and the documentation I linked above is clear enough about it (plus you'll get a warning when you'll manage more than 25 nodes without licence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again. It is fixed now. Centos's default iptables was blocking it. –